# The improper integral $ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{1-x^6}} dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I've ran into this improper integral:

$$
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{1-x^6}} dx
$$

I've tried the substitution $t=\sqrt x$ without success.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Yaron.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Substitute $u = x^6$, $x=u^{1/6}$, $dx = (1/6) u^{-5/6} du$.  Then look up what a beta function is.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function

I get after substitution

$$\frac16 \int_0^1 du \, u^{-5/6} u^{1/12}(1-u)^{-1/2}$$

which takes the value

$$\frac16 \frac{\Gamma\left( \frac14 \right ) \Gamma \left ( \frac12 \right)}{\Gamma\left ( \frac{3}{4} \right)} = \frac{\Gamma^2\left(\frac14\right)}{6 \sqrt{2\pi}}$$

Comment: hi,
I looked the "beta function" up and I didn't find anything that is very similar to my integral.

Comment: The integral seems to be missing the $u^{1/12}$ from the $\sqrt{x}$, but it seems to be picked up again in the answer.

Comment: @robjohn: forgot to put it in, but had it in my answer all along.  Am editing now, thanks.

Comment: The rght side of the last equation appears to be high by a factor of $\sqrt\pi$.

Comment: @robjohn: ugh, not my day.  Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $t=x^6$ and you get
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{1-x^6}}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac16\int_0^1t^{-3/4}(1-t)^{-1/2}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac16\mathrm{B}\left(\frac14,\frac12\right)\tag{$\ast$}\\
&=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac14\right)\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)}{6\,\Gamma\left(\frac34\right)}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{6}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac14\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac34\right)}\\
&=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac14\right)^2}{6\sqrt{2\pi}}
\end{align}
$$
The last equation is due to the reflection formula: $\displaystyle\Gamma(x)\,\Gamma(1-x)=\frac\pi{\sin(\pi x)}$

$(\ast)$ follows from $\displaystyle\mathrm{B}(x,y)=\int_0^1t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}\,\mathrm{d}t=\frac{\Gamma(x)\,\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$

Answer (score 0):

Letting $x^3=\sin \theta$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\frac{1}{3} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin ^{2\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)-1} \theta \cos ^{2\left(\frac{1}{2}-1\right)} \theta d \theta \\
& =\frac{1}{6} B\left(\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{2}\right) \\
& =\frac{1}{6} \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)} \\
& =\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{6} \frac{\Gamma^2\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{4}\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}  \\
& =\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{6} \frac{\Gamma^2\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}{\pi \csc \left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)} \quad \textrm{(By the reflection property of Gamma function.) } \\&=\frac{\Gamma^2\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}{6 \sqrt{2 \pi}}
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $u^6=x^4$ or $u=x^{3/2}$. Then the integral is $$\frac23\int_0^1\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^4}}dx$$which is $\frac{\varpi}3$, where $\varpi$ is the Lemniscate constant.